# Recup input value through screen manager kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want to catch a value from my first screen into my thirdscreen.

In the first, I write my name in an input field.
I go to the next window.

And I try to show my name in this last window.

So I share the code with you and I hope I will find an issue.

Python code :

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen



#define ou different screens
class FirstWindow(Screen):
    def envoyer(self):
        name = self.ids.nom_input.text

        self.ids.my_name.text = name


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class ThirdWindow(Screen):
    #PROBLEM HERE
    def on_press(self):
        self.ids.recup_infos.text = self.root.get_screen('FirstWindow').ids.my_name.text


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MonWidget(Widget):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file('new_window.kv')

class AwesomeApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (0,0,0,0)
        return kv

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

My KV CODE :

```
WindowManager:
    FirstWindow:
    SecondWindow:
    ThirdWindow:




<FirstWindow>:
    name: "romain"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            id: my_name
            text: "Entrez votre nom"
            font_size: 32

        TextInput:
            id: nom_input
            multiline: False
            size_hint: (1, .5)

        Button:
            text: "Next screen"
            font_size: 32
            on_press: root.envoyer()
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Mickael"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            


<SecondWindow>:
    name: "Mickael"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Entre votre ville"
            font_size: 32

        TextInput:
            id: ville_input
            multiline: False
            size_hint: (1, .5)


        Button:
            text: "Vérifier les infos"
            font_size: 32
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "foncier"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

        Button:
            text: "go back first screen"
            font_size: 32
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "romain"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

    


<ThirdWindow>:
    name: "foncier"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Verifier : "
            font_size: 32


        Label:
            id: recup_infos
            text: ""
            font_size: 32
            color: 'white'


        Button:
            text: "On press"
            font_size: 32
            #Problem HERE
            on_press: root.on_press()

        Button:
            text: "Précedent"
            font_size: 32
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Mickael"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

Could you help me ?
Thank you
Romain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `on_press` method:

```python
def on_press(self):
    self.ids.recup_infos.text = self.root.get_screen('FirstWindow').ids.my_name.text
```

`self.root.get_screen('FirstWindow').ids.my_name.text` isn't the correct way to get access to widgets outside of the class that you are in right now, or in this situation, screen. The correct way is to use the `App.get_running_app()` method:

```python
self.ids.recup_infos.text = App.get_running_app().root.ids.First.ids.my_name.text
```

But before doing that, you have to give ids to the screens of your app, so that the `First` argument of the method demonstrated above actually makes sense:

```kivy
WindowManager:
    FirstWindow:
        id: First 
        # "First" is the id of the FirstWindow class
        # which can also explain why there was a "First" arg
        # inside "App.get_running_app().root.ids.First.ids.my_name.text"
    SecondWindow:
        id: Second
    ThirdWindow:
        id: Third
```

Still confused to why this works? Let's divide the attributes of `App.get_running_app().root.ids.First.ids.my_name.text` into 3 parts:

- `App.get_running_app()`: this method returns the location of your running App class, in this case `AwesomeApp`. This also acts as `self` if you were to get the variable inside the App object itself
- `.root.ids.First`: if you read the Kivy documentation, or just simply watched Kivy course videos online, carefully, you should know that `self.root.ids` inside the App object returns a list of ids of the widgets inside your root widget. In this case, `App.get_running_app().root.ids` is doing the same thing here, and your screens are passed in the `ScreenManager` root widget, hence make `First` an available attribute in `App.get_running_app().root.ids`
- `.ids.my_name.text`: same as above, `App.get_running_app().root.ids.First` acts the same as `self` if you were to run it in your `FirstWindow` class, which gives you the opportunity to get access to variables outside of your working classes/screens